# VS 2013 - Static data in STL template classes and its effect on passing STL objects across DLL boundary

Tags: c++, dll, stl, visual-studio-2013

I read this old [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172396) that says it is a problem to pass STL objects across Dll boundary. Is this still valid? I ran "Steps to reproduce the behavior" at the end of the article and could not reproduce it in visual studio 2013.

I am interested in passing STL objects and containers (string, vector, map, shared_ptr etc) freely to and from my Dll (as if the dll were just a static library) and this article is the only threat that I foresee.

I fully control both the Dll and the clients of the Dll (they are compiled using the same compiler, VS 2013, same compiler settings, and use /MD)

Comment: Yes it is still valid. I mean unless you can guaranty that the .dll uses the same compiler and configuration (Debug, Release ...) as your application you can not safely pass stl objects across the boundary. One reason is different compilers have slightly different implementations. Also you will have more than 1 independent heap if different compilers or different configurations are used. You can not allocate memory in 1 heap and free it in a second this will corrupt the heap.

Comment: I guarantee same compiler, same compiler options and dynamic link to CRT (/MD) for both dll and the application. Is there any scenario (think ALL ways of passing ALL stl objects to or from the dll) that will cause an access violation?

Comment: You should be fine in this case.

Comment: Should be fine +1. My current commercial project is working like this. We are using VS2012.